# Generate Random Letters in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, char

hey guys this is my problem..

I want to generate random letters in an specific length of a word, but the Starting Letter should corresponds to value of the variable I declare.

Example:

- `A3` should generate `AER`
- `A5` should generate `AJIEH`
- `B2` should generate `BJ`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you really don't know how to do this try to wright it down on paper the steps it would take and then try to code to the specs. Then if you have a problem on a specific section then edit your question.

Comment: And apparently I can't spell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with the variable names will be tedious (although it is possible I suppose through reflection). You could, however, try something like this:

```
public static String genString(char first, int len) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 1 ; i < len ; i++)
        s += (char)(Math.random() * ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A');
    return first + s;
}
```

---

For example:

```
System.out.println(genString('A', 4));
```

Output (one of many possible):

> AVGH

Comment: THanks man! youre the man! I learned a lot from this code

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept ;D